# npm on windows cannot use a node_modules folder inside a vagrant shared folder

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, vagrant

npm on windows cant seem to use a node_modules folder installed inside a vagrant shared folder. why is that? I was running ubuntu with vagrant at the time when i set up the node_modules folder

```
C:\Users\admin\home\project>npm -v
4.0.5

C:\Users\admin\home\project>npm run build

> project.js@1.0.0 build C:\Users\admin\home\project
> webpack --display-error-details

'webpack' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! project.js@1.0.0 build: `webpack --display-error-details`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project.js@1.0.0 build script 'webpack --display-error-details'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the project.js package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack --display-error-details
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs project.js
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls project.js
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\home\project\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you run `npm install` on your Win machine? If *node_modules/* still contains the packages installed for Linux, this could result in this error message.

Comment: @KonstantinA.Magg No, i did not do that. wouldnt that overwrite the linux packages inside the node_modules folder? windows can't use the node_modules folder created in the virtual machine?

Comment: Hi @wiel, did a `npm install` under the target OS solve your issue?

Comment: @KonstantinA.Magg yes it did. i guess i have to keep two separate projects for now